# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Science Fiction & Fantasy's [3rd moderator election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Richard] [image: Thaddeus]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6319710861787136/0).

Also, please join me in thanking [PearsonArtPhoto](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98/pearsonartphoto) as he steps down as a moderator after 3 years of service.

Comment: Congrats @PearsonArtPhoto! "[`The #1 thing that I felt I did as a moderator was to re-open that question, which was closed as a general reference.`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19739075#19739075)". Must be a good feeling to know that you achieved something you're happy about and proud of in your tenure!

Comment: LOL, I had no idea that quote'd stick around. Still, I was glad to get the Tom Bombadil question re-opened.

Comment: Congrats to both of you.

Answer (score 28):

Let me be the first to congratulate @PearsonArtPhoto on his sterling service to the site. I know he's not been especially active in the past few months but as one of the earliest moderators, he was responsible for making this site the success it is now.

A firm round of applause is in order...

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Congrats from me to the successful candidates, and kudos to all who nominated themselves for this.  It can be a horrible and thankless job, so let's start on a high note!

I've no doubt that the site is going to continue going forward in good hands.  Onwards!

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for this post after seeing the moderator flag beside Thaddeus' name. Finally found it.

Late congrats to both @Richard and @Thaddeus. I'm sure you'll do a great job.

Late thanks to @PearsonArtPhoto. You may now rest.

Finally, thank you and well done to all who nominated themselves. Don't be disappointed. There are a lot of ways to help building this great site.